# retornar un arrayList en Java

Tags: java, poo

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en donde debo realizar un método `encontrarIncorrectos` en la búsqueda de los estados de tipo `E`, pero me está contando 4 teléfonos, en vez de buscar los que pertenecen al rango `E`.

Clase Telefono

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contacto {

// Atributos
private String cedula;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private Direccion direccion;
private ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;


// Metodos

public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {

    telefonos.add(telefono);
}

public void mostrarTelefonos() {
    Telefono telf = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
        telf = telefonos.get(i);
        if (telf.getEstado().equals("C")) {
            System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos() {
    /**
     * Crear un método recuperarIncorrectos, no recibe nada y retorna un
     * ArrayList de Telefono, con todos los teléfonos en estado E (Error)
     */

    Telefono telf = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
        telf = telefonos.get(i);
        if (telf.getEstado().equals("E")) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return telefonos;

}

// Constructor
public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
    super();
    telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;

}

public void imprimir() {

    System.out.println("****" + nombre + " " + apellido + "*******");
    if (this.getDireccion() != null) {
        System.out.println(
                "Direccion: " + this.direccion.getCallePrincipal() + " y " + this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No tienne asociada una direccion");
    }
}

// Getters && Setters

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}

public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

}
```

Clase Main

```
package com.cmc.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.cmc.entidades.Contacto;
import com.cmc.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestIncorrectos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contacto contacto=new Contacto("1714616123","Carmen","Estrada");
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Convencional"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", null));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Movil"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("2375467", "convencional"));
    
    ArrayList<Telefono> telefono=contacto.recuperarIncorrectos();
    System.out.println("Incorrectos: "+ telefono.size());
    
}

}
```

El resultado que me brinda del metodo `recuperarIncorrectos` es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado esperado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

> Crear un método `recuperarIncorrectos`, no recibe nada y retorna un
> ArrayList de `Telefono`, con todos los teléfonos en estado `E`
> (Error)
>
> IMPORTANTE: No se puede modificar la clase TestIncorrectos

Mi duda es: ¿por qué cuenta los 4 teléfonos en vez de los 2 que están asignados a `E`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en el método recuperarIncorrectos() es que estas usando la variable **i** como indice en el **for** y como contador dentro del **if**, por eso aumenta incorrectamente, deberías crear una variable nueva (fuera del for) para usar como contador e iniciarla en cero: *int contador = 0;* Por último debes retornar **contador**.

También hay que cambiar el tipo de retorno de la función a **int** si quieres regresar la cantidad de teléfonos de clase "E". Esto se debe a que estas retornando **contador** que es de tipo int, en este caso.
Para retornar un ArrayList<Telefono> es correcto y no hay que hacer cambios.

```
// cambiar ArrayList<Telefono> a int 
public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos() {
  Telefono telf = null;
  int contador = 0;  // nueva variable
  for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
    telf = telefonos.get(i);
    if (telf.getEstado().equals("E")) {
        i++; // cambiar esta i por 'contador'
    }
  }
  return telefonos; // retornar contador
}
```

Igualmente, esto no resuelve la consigna del ejercicio, aunque está cerca.

En lugar de crear un **contador** debes crear un ArrayList<Telefono> y cuando se  ingresa en el **if** agregar dicho 'teléfono' al ArrayList. Finalmente retornar el ArrayList. *(no agrego el código para que intentes resolverlo)*

Comment: Deberia quedarme de la siguiente manera no? public ArrayList<Telefono> recuperarIncorrectos() {
  ArrayList<Telefono> resultado = new ArrayList<Telefono>();

  Telefono telf = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
   telf = telefonos.get(i);

   if (telf.getEstado().equals("E")) {
    resultado.add(telf);
   }

  }
  return resultado;

 }

Comment: Si, está un poco difícil de leer en el comentario pero es correcto, igual si te ayuda lo agrego a la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Lo he colocado como respuesta, puedes mirar nuevamente. Entendí lo que me dijiste y me ejecuta de manera correcta, pero me gustaría saber tu opinion PD: Estoy aprendiendo a usar StackOverFlow

Comment: Si es correcto. Pero lo importante es que lo ejecutes para ver si funciona.

Comment: Si amigo funciona perfecto, gracias por tu aclaración. Me agrada que no den respuestas y mejor sea una guía para un mejor entendimiento.

Comment: Buena suerte con tu aprendizaje. Saludos